# предупреждение makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

Получаю предупреждение при передачи адреса в функцию.
Предупреждение

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'writeFlashBuffer' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

Функция имеет вид

```
void writeFlashBuffer(uint8_t *pBuffer, uint32_t NumberSector, uint32_t addrBegin, uint32_t Size);
```

вид вызова функции

```
writeFlashBuffer(*(uint8_t*)&addr, sector, 0, 1024);
```

где тип перемеренной

```
addr - это uint32_t
sector - это uint32_t
```

если добавить uint8_t*

```
writeFlashBuffer((uint8_t*)*(uint8_t*)&addr, sector, 0, 1024);
```

то предупреждение меняется на

```
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Присмотритесь сюда

```
writeFlashBuffer(*(uint8_t*)&addr, sector, 0, 1024);
```

Вы первым параметром передаете `*(uint8_t*)&addr`. Разворачиваем справа на лево. У целочисленной переменной берем адрес, кастуем к нужному типу а потом разыменовываем . По факту вернулись к тому, с чего начали.

`writeFlashBuffer` хочет адрес буфера.

Поэтому, возможно, правильный вызов выглядит так

```
writeFlashBuffer(&addr, sector, 0, 1024);
```

если addr - это именно данные.

но если addr содержит именно адрес (странно, но чего в си не бывает), то тогда вызов выглядит так

```
writeFlashBuffer((uint8_t*)addr, sector, 0, 1024);
```